# Heroku Command Error - Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: node.js, heroku, macos-sierra

I was trying to host my NodeJS app to Heroku but got stuck on an error.

```
heroku create

 ▸    Unexpected character during netrc parsing at character a:
 ▸    machine mdlisten.unfuddle.com
 ▸    login augustinepa
 ▸    password xxxxxxx@#machine api.heroku.com
 ▸    password 82556905-3dec-4b71-8db7-0f1eb05ff540
 ▸    login xxxxxx@gmail.com
 ▸    machine git.heroku.com
 ▸    password 82556905-3dec-4b71-8db7-0f1eb05ff540
 ▸    login xxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Note: I just masked my email-password with xxxxxx

I am getting the same error even I try to execute commands like **"heroku logout, heroku login etc."**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this issue by clearing .netrc from the home directory.

Hope this would be helpful for some one got similar issue.